# How to access Blogger and YouTube from any other URLs

Tags: youtube, blogger, url

Is there any way to access Blogger and YouTube from any subdomain of Google?

For example can I access Blogger from a link like `https://blablabal.google.com`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that for (unless you are trying to bypass a firewall)?

Comment: Thats right, They are both filtered in my country.

Comment: Not that I can see. `youtube.google.com` doesn't resolve to anything. `blogger.google.com` redirects to `blogger.com`. You might have to try specific IP addresses or, more practically, use an open proxy.

Comment: sometimes all ports other that http port and https port, including most proxies porsts are closed, that's when I can not access my personal blog by any means. Just google is allway available